# DOTNET CLI RC2 EF migrations

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2, dotnet-cli

I just migrated to RC2 from RC1 and having a really hard time getting the ef commands and migrations to work.

I've read several other questions and have ran into the problem that's getting described in this [link](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/cli/dotnet.html#dotnet-ef) as a known issue.

The problem is that if I follow the instructions and create a brand new console application (.core) I'm still getting the following message:

> This preview of Entity Framework tools does not support targeting class library projects in ASP.NET Core and .NET Core applications. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798221 for details and workarounds.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to revert to rc1?

Comment: Now everything seems to have broken, getting this message: Invoking dependency command 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli' in project 'mysite'
projectdependenciescommandresolver: C:\mysite\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\DAL.runtimeconfig.json does not exist
No executable found matching command "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli"

Comment: yes a surprisingly bad nightmare!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you do this migration ? I ask because in my case everything works time - as for now.

In my case I have removed all RC1 components first and then I have installed new RC2 components...

Next I have created new APS project using new Visual Studio Templates to get correct references and just moved my code to this new project.

Of course it's few things which I had to update in my code, but everything works fine for me including ef commands and migrations.

As you can read in [ASP.NET Core installation guide](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows)

> Before you start
>
> Remove all previous versions of .NET Core from your system by using Add/Remove programs.

*You need RC1 setup file to uninstall this component - if you do not have it, check StackOverflow - you can find link to download missing files.*

Try follow the docs:

- [ASP.NET Migration](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/index.html)
- [Migrating from ASP.NET 5 RC1 to ASP.NET
  Core](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html)
- [Migrating from DNX to .NET Core CLI](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/dnx-migration.html)

> ASP.NET 5 RC1 apps were based on the .NET Execution Environment (DNX)
>   and made use of DNX specific features. ASP.NET Core RC2 is based on
>   .NET Core, so you must first migrate your application to the new .NET
>   Core project model. See  [Migrating from DNX to .NET Core CLI](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/dnx-migration.html) for more
>   information.

Hope this help you :)

Comment: Note that old version of .NET Core may be called "Microsoft Dotnet CLI for Windows"

Comment: Thanks. I followed several guides on tha I found on google. I don't know if this was the root of the problem but the old commands, dnx, dnvm dnu etc. still worked and I'm not so sure if the uninstallation of RC1 was succesfull. Maybe that's what caused the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure... But in my case I have deleted old 'dnx' files and npm cache files form disk (manually from my user folder), and like I said I have used new clean template so I'm sure that I had correct references in project.json... Maybe you have still some old references in project.json ?

Comment: I suggest create new project and move your code to this new project, or at least compare project.json files...